# How to compile Imagick with libwebp for Webp image support

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, pecl, webp, intervention

I have ImageMagick, Imagick and Webp library installed locally on OSX and trying to save images as Webp with the Intervention Image library, but receiving the following error:

`Webp format is not supported by Imagick installation.`

After looking at the Intervention Image documentation (http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/formats) I can see that the Imagick extension needs to be 'compiled with libwebp support', however there is no instructions for doing this and after much searching I cannot find a solution

I have Imagick installed via `pecl` - there doesn't seem to be an install flag such as `--with-libwebp` as it seems there used to be for installing using `brew`

> PHP Version: 7.2
>
> ImageMagick version: 7.0.8-53
>
> Imagick version: 3.4.4
>
> OSX Version: 10.14.5

Answer (score 1):

You have to install libwebp with Imagemagick, not Imagick.

I do not think you need to do anything special in the Imagemagick .configuration file using --with libwebp, when compiling it from source with webp.

I am on OSX Sierra. I install all my delegates from MacPorts and then installed Imagemagick 7.0.8.53 from source. That works well for me. All that I need is to have MacPorts install libwebp along with all my other desired delegates.  Here is my configuration file. Note there is no special --with webp included.

```
./configure CC=/opt/local/bin/clang-mp-3.9 CXX=/opt/local/bin/clang++-mp-3.9 \
CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/local/include' LDFLAGS='-L/opt/local/lib' \
--enable-openmp \
--enable-delegate-build --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-opencl \
--with-modules --with-quantum-depth=16 --without-wmf --with-rsvg \
--disable-silent-rules --disable-dependency-tracking --without-pango \
--with-lqr --with-gslib --with-gs-font-dir=/opt/local/share/ghostscript/fonts/
```

```
I simply do the .configuration ...
Then make clean
Then make
Then sudo make install
```

I do not know how to install libwebp once you already have your Imagemagick binary installed.